# 500 Internal server error while integrating Payment Gateway in Laravel

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments

The view on the URL  //user/deposit/create has been created to enable the selection of a Payment Gateway. The gateway file was added as a Controller in the Controllers file (The key methods are the CollectFunds Method and the Give Funds Method.

Then we have a PostJSON function, as shown below.-

The challenge is after going to the Portal to test (
Selecting the Payment Method,  Entering the Deposit Amount and Description, then Clicking the submit button to prompt the payment from the user's phone, the following error comes without describing where it came from) - 500 Internal server error! And the final URL stops at user/deposit/bpal/submit. Kindly guide me on how to handle this. Below is the source code of the payment controller.

```
class BpalController extends Controller
{
    var $url = 'https://test.api.testintegrator.com';
    var $api_key = 'testkeyhere';
    var $secret = 'secretkeyhere';

    public function CollectFunds($tranId, $amount, $phone, $name, $reason)
    {
        $endPoint = $this->url.'/collections/create';
        $service_id = 2;
        if (Str::startsWith($phone, '25678') || Str::startsWith($phone, '25677')
            || Str::startsWith($phone, '25676')) {
            $service_id = 5;
        }
        if (Str::startsWith($phone, '25675') || Str::startsWith($phone, '25670')
            || Str::startsWith($phone, '25674')) {
            $service_id = 1;
        }

        $payload = [
            'request' => [
                'vendor_tran_ref' => $tranId,
                'service_id' => $service_id,
                'post_data' => [
                    ['key' => 'amount', 'value' => $amount],
                    ['key' => 'telephone', 'value' => $phone],
                    ['key' => 'name', 'value' => $name],
                    ['key' => 'reason', 'value' => $reason]
                ]
            ]
        ];

        return $this->postJson($endPoint, $payload, '');
    }

    public function GiveFunds($tranId, $amount, $phone, $name, $reason)
    {
        $endPoint = $this->url.'/payments/create';
        $service_id = 2;
        if (Str::startsWith($phone, '25678') || Str::startsWith($phone, '25677')
            || Str::startsWith($phone, '25676')) {
            $service_id = 5;
        }
        if (Str::startsWith($phone, '25675') || Str::startsWith($phone, '25670')
            || Str::startsWith($phone, '25674')) {
            $service_id = 1;
        }
        $payload = [
            'request' => [
                'vendor_tran_ref' => $tranId,
                'service_id' => $service_id,
                'post_data' => [
                    ['key' => 'amount', 'value' => $amount],
                    ['key' => 'telephone', 'value' => $phone],
                    ['key' => 'name', 'value' => $name],
                    ['key' => 'reason', 'value' => $reason]
                ]
            ]
        ];

        $private_key = hash_hmac('sha256', $this->api_key.$tranId, $this->secret);

        return $this->postJson($endPoint, $payload, $private_key);
    }


    function postJson($endPoint, $payload, $private_key)
    {

        //Initiate cURL.
        $ch = curl_init($endPoint);
        //Encode the array into JSON.
        $jsonDataEncoded = json_encode($payload);
        //Tell cURL that we want to send a POST request.
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        //Attach our encoded JSON string to the POST fields.
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonDataEncoded);
        //Set the content type to application/json
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'x-api-key: '.$this->api_key,
            'x-private-key: '.$private_key,
        ));

        //return response instead of outputting
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        //close connection
        curl_close($ch);

        $result = json_decode($result);

        return $result->response_data;
    }
}
```

Kindly advise on how to solve the error
500 Internal server error!

Tried depositing the required amount by selecting the Payment Gateway, Deposit Amount, Description,  and clicking the submit button
through /user/deposit/create. I expected the system to prompt a mobile payment on the user's phone, but this didn't happen.

After clicking submit, it returns an error on this page:  /user/deposit/bpal/submit. The error is 500 Internal server error! Would you please advise?

Comment: enable ``APP_DEBUG=true`` in the ``.env`` file and then repeat the process, you'll get the error message.

Comment: Thank you.  But APP_DEBUG=true is enabled, yet there's no change

Comment: then check the ``laravel.log`` file.